# loading a view to webview..

Tags: android, view, webview, gif

i am trying to load a gif image from assets folder.. i am following the below link

http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-3/

now the problem here is my gif is a large so only a portion of the image is being displayed in the view.. thus i want to

```
i want to display the gif in an xml file that has a webview as a child..
```

to attend the above aim, i did the following

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_about);
 WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
 GifWebView view = new GifWebView(this, "file:///android_asset/ab.gif");     
 webView.addView(view);
```

but am getting the following error

```
 Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/ab.gif
 I/chromium(1139): [INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "Not allowed to load local resource:
                 file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png", 
                  source: data:text/html,chromewebdata (12)
```

so how do i display the view in webview in an xml??

Answer (score 0):

Gif are supported in web view for this u need to generate your own html file like as follow,

```
 <html>
<body bgcolor="white">
    <table width="100%" height="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <font color="gray">Some text you display</font>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <img src="yourGIF.gif">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

kept this html inside your assess folder.load that url inside web view

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/your_html.html");
```